# Translate UrlFetchApp Response HTML To Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm new to working with APIs/CURL and trying to figure out how to get a response (not response code) into a sheet. Here's my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/[Thread_Id]";
  var headers = {
             "contentType": "application/json",
             "headers":{"Authorization": "Bearer [Token]"}
             };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var text = response.getResponseCode();
  var dataParse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataStr = JSON.stringify(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(text);
  Logger.log(dataParse);
  Logger.log(dataStr);
}
```

For testing, I've tried outputting the `dataParse` and `dataStr` with the following results:

*dataParse*

```
{user_ids=[], shared_folder_ids=[abcdabcd], expanded_user_ids=[abcdabcd], html=<h1 id='abcdabcd'Test Report</h1>

<div data-section-style='13'><table id=......<br/></td><td id='s:abcabcabc' style='background-color:#F5FAFF;'><span
 id='s:abcabcabc'>Active (Product)</span>....
```

*dataStr*

```
{\"thread\":{\"author_id\":\"abcabcabc\",\"thread_class\":\"document\",\"id\":\"abcabcabc\",\"created_usec\":123456789,\"updated_usec\":123456789,\"title\":\"Test
Report\",\"link\":\"https:\\/\\/quip.com\\/abcabcabc\",\"type\":\"spreadsheet\"},\"user_ids\":[],\"shared_folder_ids\":[\"abcabcabc\"],\"expanded_user_ids\".....
```

So my question is: Is there a way to convert either of those results into a Google Spreadsheet or will I need to write my own conversion function? Or am I coming at this from a completely wrong angle?

(Side question, the results returned in `Logger.log` are way less than the actual results when using CURL. Does `Logger` truncate results?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert either of those results into a Google Spreadsheet or will I need to write my own conversion function? Or am I coming at this from a completely wrong angle?

You have to build your own conversion function or get one from someone else.

Regarding the side question, [log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object)) doesn't mention limits.